# How to stop map function on specific number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the below code. How can I limit the `map` function as reached the specific index? For example as the following code is returning all elements (as it is supposes to be) like `everest_k2_kangchenjunga_lhotse` but I need to get ONLY TWO first element which the result look like `everest_k2`

```
var mountains  = $(".mapdata ul:nth-child(1) li").map(function () {
  return $(this).text().toLowerCase();
}).get().join('_');
```

```js
var mountains  = $(".mapdata ul:nth-child(1) li").map(function () {
  return $(this).text().toLowerCase();
}).get().join('_');
console.log(mountains );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mapdata">
  <ul>
    <li>Everest</li>
    <li>K2</li>
    <li>Kangchenjunga</li>
    <li>Lhotse</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Caspian</li>
    <li>Superior</li>
    <li>Victoria</li>
    <li>Tanganyika</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Does a `.slice(0, 2)` before `.map` not work or is the index not fixed?

Comment: You can't "stop" `.map`. You can only limit the input size before calling `.map` e.g. with `.slice`, as mentioned.

Comment: @user4642212 already gave you the answer :)